# What oil should I use for Hyundai Sonata 2004?

Tags: oil, oil-change

What oil should I use for this car?
How do I know when I should change the oil for my car?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [owner's manual](https://carmanuals2.com/get/hyundai-sonata-2004-owner-s-manual-33548), it depends on the climate you live in:

```
+----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|             Climate              |             Oil Grade              |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| Hot (ABOVE 32°F OR 0°C)          | SAE 20W-40, SAE 20W-50             |
| Normal (ABOVE -10°F OR -23°C)    | SAE 10W-30, SAE 10W-40, SAE 10W-50 |
| Cold (BELOW 100°F OR 38°C) [sic] | SAE 5W-30, SAE 5W-40               |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

I assume that the cold climate temperature range should really say "Below -10°F"

**Quantities**

For the 4-cylinder engine:

- without filter: 4.0 L
- with filter: 4.3 L

For the 2.7 V6:

- without filter: 4.2 L
- with filter: 4.5 L

Comment: Temperature is all messed up dude..

Comment: @Anarach I know, the fact that this mistake is in the owner's manual is a real shocker